# reading same element but different value

Tags: c#, xml

I'm new to C# and I was wondering if it were possible to do this:

I have multiple elements with the same name but different values and I want to compare them one-by-one.

Example: (Local) file.txt hash with (URL) file.text hash.

I tried with some codes but I can't find/create anything good.  This is what I've tried:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load("sample.xml");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("FileName");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
  MessageBox.Show(node.ToString());
}
```

There are around 13,000 XML records.

I have this XML:

```
<File FileName="file.txt" FileHash="1C395F6D2AA729A607E69DCA73F8205CEFD26AA4" FileSize="2337488" />
<File FileName="file2.txt" FileHash="B313285D73CA635EB76B8082737BDCF82481DCD0" FileSize="640000" />
<File FileName="file3.txt" FileHash="2D797F6840FB00D86B560290DD0A2A76E3FA90D8" FileSize="157" />
<File FileName="file4.txt" FileHash="D7AC7873B2A00B27451E485C65BF8562237A2562" FileSize="4702208" />
<File FileName="file5.txt" FileHash="8D89AC439D8FD44C9D9EF57D27A160BDB056D63D" FileSize="1052" />
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML?

Comment: Your XML is not valid. You can only have one element at the root. If you surrounded the whole thing with `<Files> ... </Files>`, then it might be ok.

Comment: Yeah it has <Files> at the start and </Files> at the end.

Comment: @JohnSaunders judging by his code, it looks like there actually is a root element surrounding those `File` elements, but it's just included in the sample

Comment: it's hers,not his. :P

Comment: `HOW` do you want to compare the results?? Which part of the algorithm is giving you troubles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand the "comparison" you're trying to do, but the following should get you started in accessing the File element attributes that you're interested in.

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System;

 public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc= new XmlDocument(); 

        try {
            xmlDoc.Load("files.xml"); 
        }catch(System.Xml.XmlException e){
            Console.WriteLine(e);   
        }

        XmlNodeList defs = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("File");

        for (int i = 0; i < defs.Count; i++)
        {
            string fn = defs[i].Attributes["FileName"].Value;
            string fh = defs[i].Attributes["FileHash"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine("File:  " + fn + "\tHash:  " + fh);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,this works now. Now i only need to find out how to compare them.

Comment: @RebecaRdi Great!  Glad it helped.  Please credit me for the solution when you get a chance.

Comment: @RebecaRdi If you post some more details about the comparison you're trying to make, you can probably get some help with that, as well.

Comment: Thanks alot David,trying to make a comparision between the hash from files1.xml (local) and web files2.xml (url)

Answer (score 0):

you have to pull the attributes out of your node

```
MessageBox.Show(node.Attributes["FileName"].Value);
```